# Can not receive notification on my Android device with Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I wrote a node.js function which sends notification on to an Android device by payload. I've deployed the index.js(file that content the function) on to Firebase Cloud Messaging.

After sending a message the log shows that the notification is sent at the same time it shows error, and I'm not able to receive notification on targeted device.

Here's my index.js file that content the function:

```
'use-strict'
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document("Users/{user_id}/notifMessages/{notification_id}").onWrite((change, context) => {
const user_id = context.params.user_id;
const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

return admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user_id).collection("notifMessages").doc(notification_id).get().then(queryResult => {
    
    const from_user_id = queryResult.data().fromUser;
    const from_message = queryResult.data().message;
    
    const from_data = admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(from_user_id).get();
    const to_data = admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user_id).get();
    
    return Promise.all([from_data, to_data]).then(result => {
    
        const from_name = result[0].data().nom;
        const to_name = result[1].data().nom;
        const tokenId = result[1].data().tokenId;
        
        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title : "Notification from : "+from_name,
                body : from_message,
                icon : "default",
                click_action: "mr.pharma_proche.TARGETNOTIFICATION"
            },
            data: {
                message : from_message,
                from_user_id : from_user_id
            }
        };
        
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenId, payload).then(result => {
        
            console.log("Notification sent : "+from_name+" to : "+to_name+" Token : "+tokenId);
            return results;
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("error, message not sent");
        });
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Please post your code here, not as an image.

Comment: What's the error? And what is the value of your `tokenId`?

Comment: Thanks guys @Phix i've edited the question by including the code.

Comment: @AL. Here're what the log shows : `Notification sent : Kanaro to : Tidjane Token : eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjIzNTBiNWY2NDM0Zjc2Y2NiM2IxMTlmZGQ4OGQxMzhjOWFjNTVmY2UiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vcGhhcm1hLXByb2NoZS1iNTA1NyIsImF1ZCI6InBoYXJtYS1wcm9jaGUtYjUwNTciLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1NDM4NTM4MjgsInVzZXJfaWQiOiJsTGljRzVvaEFWVW1EaGlxcXB1RHgyU2tGRmsxIiwic3ViIjoibExpY0c1b2hBVlVtRGhpcXFwdUR4MlNrRkZrMSIsImlhdCI6MTU0Mzg1MzgzNywiZXhwIjoxNTQzODU3NDM3LCJlbWFpbCI6InRpakBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6ZmFsc2UsImZpcmViYXNlIjp7ImlkZW50aXRpZXMiOnsiZW1haWwiOlsid...`

Comment: @AL. it shows also :   `error, message not sent`

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid fcm token.

Comment: @AL. I got the tokenId by this code : `String tokenId = getTokenResult.getToken();
                                Map<String, Object> tokenMap = new HashMap<>();
                                tokenMap.put("tokenId", tokenId);` and i finally store it on database.

Comment: I may have had it wrong. It's been a while since I checked the format of the FCM tokens. Nonetheless, your requests are failing for a reason. It would help if you could log the actual error response.